# How to clear form input in ReactJs after add product successfully

Tags: reactjs

I would like to clear my Form input after submit form but I can't. How can I do that

This is my code for that

```
const onHandleSubmit = (e) => {
    if (values.name.trim() === "") {
      setIsValid(false);
    }
    else {
      createProductRequest(values, imageAsFile);
    }
  };
```

This is my setdefaultValue

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
    image: "",
    name: "",
    price: 0,
    description: "",
    categoty: "",
  });
```

This is my button in form

```
<Button
    btnText="Submit"
    size="btn-md"
    onClick={onHandleSubmit}
    disabled={isValid}
 />
```

My button is imported from another folder, so I have do like that

They require I must set that in useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (type.CREATE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS) {
      fetchProductRequest();
    }
  }, [fetchProductRequest, type]);
```

I have do like this

```
   useEffect(() => {
        if (type.CREATE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS) {
          fetchProductRequest();
          const defaultValues = {
            image: "",
            name: "",
            price: 0,
            description: "",
            categoty: "",
          }
          setValues(defaultValues)
        }
      }, [fetchProductRequest, type

]);
```

But it doesn't work

I custom my form from react-bootstrap

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just add :

```
setValues({
    image: "",
    name: "",
    price: 0,
    description: "",
    categoty: "",
  })
```

after  `createProductRequest(values, imageAsFile);`

like :

```
 else {
      createProductRequest(values, imageAsFile);
  setValues({
    image: "",
    name: "",
    price: 0,
    description: "",
    categoty: "",
  })
    }
```

Comment: But I do not allow todo like that, because it can be fail by some reason!

Comment: I have adit my question above, Could you help me please check it again, and can you support me

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to call requests from the body of the component, in order to avoid problems with data synchronization in store. For these purposes, use middlewares such as redux-thunk or redux-sagas. In them, after a successful response from the server, call the method to clear the input:

```html
const defaultValues = {
  image: "",
  name: "",
  price: 0,
  description: "",
  categoty: "",
}

setValues(defaultValues)
```